# Access to the Maps Application Data Store

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on a Friend Finder type mapping application and have lots of bits of it working such as mapping with overlays. I would like to use some of the built-in functionality of the current Android Maps application, which I can call using an intent. However, once I've 'created' a walking route using the Maps app, I'd then like to be able to access the route which appears to be stored as an Overlay in the Maps data store. Is there any way for my own app to access this data or do I have to make the http call myself with the start and end locations?

I'm aware of the Map API Terms & Conditions restrictions but this should be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way for my own app to access this data

No, sorry. Beyond the published `Intent` system, there is no API for the Google Maps Android application.